Correct PDF code structure in PDF writer class for C# application
I have written a simple PDF writer class for a Windows Forms C# application, but I am having some issues with the PDF output.
The application creates and writes to the file successfully, however when I open the file in a PDF viewer, only the first line (Hello world!) is shown, and the next two lines which should be in the document are not visible.
When I open the file in notepad, this is the output:
%PDF-1.7
1 0 obj
<< /Type /Catalog
/Pages 2 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<< /Type /Pages
/Kids [3 0 R]
/Count 1
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<< /Type /Page
/Parent 2 0 R
/Resources << >>
/Contents 4 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<< /Length 300 >>
stream
BT
/Arial 12 Tf
50 700 Td
(Hello world!) Tj
50 680 Td
(01/05/2024 08:50:34) Tj
50 660 Td
(29 April 2024 - 01 May 2024) Tj
ET
endstream
endobj
<<
/Type /Metadata
/Subtype /XML
/Length 100
>>
stream
<?xpacket begin="﻿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?>
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/">
</x:xmpmeta>
<?xpacket end="w"?>
endstream
endobj
<< /MarkInfo << /Marked true >> >>
endobj
<< /Type /StructTreeRoot >>
endobj
xref
0 5
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000009 00000 n 
0000000055 00000 n 
0000000108 00000 n 
0000000197 00000 n 
trailer
<< /Root 1 0 R
/Metadata 5 0 R
/MarkInfo 6 0 R
/StructTreeRoot 7 0 R
/Size 5
>>
startxref
254
%%EOF

Why is only the first line being shown? Is there an error in my PDF code structure? Or is it an issue with the PDF viewer?
Please note, I don't want to use an external PDF writer library for this project.

The Td operator work this way:

Your first Td operator moves the drawing position to (50, 700) but the second one moves it to (100, 1380) which is outside the page visible area.
This fix
BT
/Arial 12 Tf
50 700 Td
(Hello world!) Tj
0 -20 Td
(01/05/2024 08:50:34) Tj
0 -20 Td
(29 April 2024 - 01 May 2024) Tj
ET

will generate this output:

Also your PDF file has several problems: the length of the page content stream  is incorrect and there is no /Arial font in /Resources dictionary. These errors

That's great. Thank you. It's my first time working with PDF construction.
